# How do I get the Area/City Name from Region ID for add address programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, custom, rest-api, customer-address

I got the state list from country code by following this [blog](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-all-regions-of-country-by-country-code-in-magento-2/) for my Magento 2 store. I want to get the Area/City name from the state/region id, is there a way or method to get it in Magento 2.3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 get does not have any concept like **Get the Area/City name from the state/region id`. In Magento 2 system, there is only one type of relationship that **State changes using country**.

**So, you can NOT get City from Region Id/State id.**

Comment: Then is there any other way or customization to do it, @AmitBera ?

Comment: Yes, possible, there are some extensions are available. You can try those https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager https://marketplace.magento.com/eltrino-srm.html